# Is it possible to highlight text in TextView without re - setText() completely?

Tags: android, textview, settext

For instance, I want to make a karaoke in a huge-huge text in a TextView.
I got an array of milliseconds and with MediaPlayer's `getCurrentTime()` I need to highlight words corresponding to this array.

The problem is if I do the refreshing with setText() method - it will halt the system completely, especially if it's several times per second.

Is there a way to highlight a text partially without re-setting it completely?

Right now we are using a webview with a html with this text and a javascript to do it word by word, but javascript is very slow on old devices so I'm looking for a way do do it in java